# Create Svg line inside a cell of table using jquery or javascript in a node js application

Tags: javascript, html, svg, jquery-svg

I only have basic knowledge of svg,

I am trying to create a line inside a table cell.
What I have achieved so far is, created the SVG Tag with the height and width as same as a table cell(SVG tag have dimensions ), and created a line tag within the SVG(Tag is in the DOM But with dimensions (0*X)).
Attaching the DOM portion

```
  <svg class="history-svg" width="100%" height="34.83" style="display: block; height: 34.83px;">
    <line x1="6.25%" y1="50%" x2="92%" y2="50%" stroke="#D6D9D8" stroke-width="1px"></line>
  </svg>
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncAMC.png)

I tried to edit SVG tag attributes using chrome inspect  HTML editor functionality, appended viewport with value 0 0 0 0. the SVG-line was visible(with dimensions). but when I tried to append using the js and from the console, there was no effect

```
  <svg viewPort='00 0 0' class="history-svg" width="100%" height="34.83" style="display: block; height: 34.83px;">
        <line x1="6.25%" y1="50%" x2="92%" y2="50%" stroke="#D6D9D8" stroke-width="1px"></line>
  </svg>
```

[Output after editing SVG as an HTML from chrome inspact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnVkz.png)

Attaching the at most possible part of the code from the javascript file responsible for creating the SVG tag:

```
const historySVGTag = $('<svg>').addClass('history-svg').attr('width','100%').attr('height',svgHeight).css('display' ,'block').css('height' ,svgHeight+'px')

historySVGTag.append($('<line>').attr('x1','6.25%').attr('y1','50%').attr('x2','92%').attr('y2','50%').attr('stroke','#D6D9D8').attr('stroke-width','1px'))

var cellSelector = '#tableID tbody tr#'+item.id+' td.col-2'

$(cellSelector).append(historySVGTag)
```

Comment: When using `width` and `height` on an outermost SVG, you must include units like `px`. Also, it should be `viewBox`, not `viewPort`, and you should set the first two values to `0` and the second two to unitless values representing your width and height.

Comment: For width, it is working with percentage and the SVG has the desired Dimensions I have shared the image for that as well. Height is provided using style attr. And I tried ViewBox with proper values (0 0 width-in-px height-in-px ) but did not worked

Comment: `viewBox` values should not have units. `width` and `height` on the outermost SVG should have units.